# Multi hashmap containsValue

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a hashmap as follows

```
Map <String, List<String>> map = new HashMap <String, List<String>>();
```

After I did a `map.put()`, my map looks something like this:

```
Key - key1
Values - [value1] 
Key - key2
Values - [value1, value2, value3]
```

Now I am reading a line from a file. File is like this:

```
Key:key2, Value:value1
```

I am storing the key1 and value1 in 2 elements called keyRead and valueRead. Inside the line reader, if I am using `containsKey()` and `containsValue()`, it is not working.

```
if(map.containsKey(keyRead){
  S.O.P("Inside key match");
  if(map.containsValue(valueRead){
     S.O.P ("Inside value match");
  }
}
```

The output is showing the inside key match but it is not showing the inside value match.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: You can't run `containsValue` on a map with `List` as the value type, while supplying a `String` argument. You need to get the key, then get the corresponding value, to retrieve the list and check if your string argument is contained therein

Comment: SOP is most likely pseduo code for System.out.println

Comment: Your map value type is `List<String>`, so basically make sure `valueRead` is also with same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something like

```
if(map.containsKey(keyRead)) {
    if(map.get(keyRead).contains(valueRead)) {
        System.out.println("Inside value match");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values are lists, not strings. If you need to check if the string is contained by the list, you need to get the list first, then invoke the contains method of that list, passing the string as argument.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to loop through the values in the list like this, btw i have not tested the code -

```
if(map.containsKey(keyRead){
    S.O.P("Inside key match");
   forEach(List l: map.get(keyRead)) {
      forEach(String s : l) {
      if(s.equals(valueRead)) {
     S.O.P ("Inside value match");
     }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: use `List.contains` instead of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, you cannot do a `containsValue` using an instance where the value is a `List`. Try using Guava's [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). This implements a `Map` where a `key` maps to multiple `values`.

`Multimap` has a [containsEntry(key, value)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#containsEntry(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) that works exactly as you desire in that it matches the key and that the list associated with the key contains the value.